# Вопрос по DAO и Repository.

Tags: java, postgresql

Здравствуйте.Ситуация примерно следующая.Пишу на java программу,которая из очереди rabbitmq получает какие-то данные(например айди записи пользователя),дальше подключается к БД,по айди берет нужные данные и использует их для отправки письма. есть 2 класса:
Класс с точкой входа в программу.

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.*;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Reception  {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "MailQueue";

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);

        Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                    throws IOException {
                String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
                processMessage(body);
                DataGet id = new DataGet();
                MailSender mail=new MailSender();
                mail.MailSending(id.DataGet(processMessage(body)));
                channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
                System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
            }
        };
        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, false, consumer);
    }

    public static int processMessage(byte[] delivery ){
        String id = new String(delivery);
        return Integer.parseInt(id);
    }
}
```

класс,отвечающий за работу с базой,передающий данные классу-отправителю:

```
public class DataGet {
    String from;
    String to;
    String subject;
    String body;


    public DataGet DataGet(int id) {

        System.out.println("got id= " + id);

        DataGet DataFromBD = new DataGet();

        String Url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/newBD";
        String UserName = "postgres";
        String UserPassword = "postgres";

        try {
            Connection DBConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(Url, UserName, UserPassword);

            Statement statement = DBConnection.createStatement();
            ResultSet Result = statement.executeQuery(
                    "select * from mailer.log where (id =id)"
            );

            while (Result.next()) {
                DataFromBD.setTo(Result.getString("to"));
                DataFromBD.setFrom(Result.getString("from"));
                DataFromBD.setSubject(Result.getString("subject"));
                DataFromBD.setBody(Result.getString("body"));
            }
            Result.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("got data: ");
        System.out.println("transmitting data to mailsender(using id= " + id + " )");

        return DataFromBD;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }
}
```

Знаю,что код не ахти(программировать начал я не так давно).Мне сказали,что  если смотреть с точки зрения паттернов код подходит под паттерн DAO, а нужно Repository, что бы в классе с обращением к базе каждый раз не создавался новый объект и надо код немного переделать(добавить bean-класс с геттерами и сеттерами). Нашел статью [статью](http://thinkinginobjects.com/2012/08/26/dont-use-dao-use-repository/).Но не совсем понял суть темы.Кто понял, о чем идет речь,пожалуйста хотя бы в 2 словах скажите,что мне нужно посмотреть\изучить и в 2 словах,что изменить...
Думаю, следует дописать следующее:Я не прошу,чтобы это сделали за меня, я прошу, чтобы меня направили,потому что хочу разобраться в данной области.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вкратце на тему DAO vs Repository. Оновной тезис приведённой вами статьи (кстати, на Хабре есть её [перевод](https://habrahabr.ru/post/263033/)) заключается в том, что со временем DAO обрастает кучей частных методов, извлекающих информацию по конкретным критериям: `getObjById`, `getObjByName`, `getObjBySomeOtherField` и т. д. Чтобы уйти от этого, предлагается использовать паттерн Repository. В Repository вместо нескольких частных методов получения объекта или списка объектов используется один - `query` - которому передаётся объект (Specification), на основании которого строится запрос к базе. Объект Specification должен содержать информацию о том, по каким признакам фильтруются результаты запроса, и уметь превращаться в валидное условие для запроса. Это позволит (при достаточно развитой иерархии Specification) динамически создавать запросы любой сложности по любым критериям.

Теперь претензии непосредственно к вашему коду:

1. Соблюдайте [Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) в именовании классов, методов и переменных.
2. Создайте отдельный класс ([bean](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans)) для хранения информации, которую вы извлекаете из базы. В DAO должна быть только логика извлечения и записи информации в базу.
3. Возможно, это опечатка: `"select * from mailer.log where (id =id)"` - вы не подставляете значение `id`
4. Используйте `PreparedStatement` вместо `Statement` - это позволит защититься от SQL-инъекций.
5. Закрывать `ResultSet` и `Connection` нужно в блоке `finally` - если в блоке `try` у вас произойдёт ошибка, они оба подвиснут в открытом состоянии.
6. Хорошей практикой считается использование пула соединений (connection pool) для получения соединений с базой. Можно использовать любой существующий, либо (если вы хотите поглубже вникнуть в тему) написать свой.
7. Также хорошей практикой считается выносить настройки (URL базы, логин/пароль пользователя) в `.properties`-файл.

И напоследок: у каждого паттерна есть своя область применения, свой список задач, которые он решает. Эту информацию можно найти в любом каталоге паттернов. Прежде чем реализовывать паттерн, проверьте, точно ли именно эти задачи вы пытаетесь решить. Если нет - велика вероятность, что вы бессмысленно усложняете свой код, и стоит отдать предпочтение более простому решению.

**Update**

Значение `id` не подставляется. Java - не PHP, подставлять переменные в строки просто так не будет. Нужно либо делать это явно при помощи `replace()`, `StringBuilder` или `PreparedStatement` (наиболее предпочтительный вариант). Сейчас у вас выполняестя запрос с условием `where (id = id)`, который возвращает все записи из таблицы, однако, ваш код вернёт только последнюю, так как перезапишет все, что вытащил до этого.

Про SQL-инъекции можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) или [здесь](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Пул соединений - это механизм, который постоянно держит открытыми фиксированное количество соединений к базе, выдаёт их другим классам и следит, чтобы одно соединение не использовалось из нескольких мест или слишком долго. Это позволяет сэкономить ресурсы на открытие/закрытие соединений и не перегружать базу большим количеством открытых соединений. Подробнее - [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/229199/) или [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/how-to-establish-a-connection-pool-in-jdbc).

`.properties`-файлы - простые текстовые файлы, содержащие информацию в виде `ключ=значение`:

```
database.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/newBD
database.user=postgres
database.password=postgres
```

Читаются [вот так](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/).

Comment: Ох,спасибище огромное.сколько полезной информации получил.
касаемо пунктов,почти со всеми согласен кроме:
3. значение подставляется,мы ведь его передаем в метод DataGet. 
ну и есть еще пару вопросов: 
1)что такое SQL-инъекции?
2) в 6 вопросе вы написали о пуле соединений.пулы помогают сэкономить ресурсы?имеет ли смысл открывать пул, если в системе может быть куча запросов на подключение к бд?
3) что такое .properties-файл и где его искать?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: а если в запросе к базе использовать конкатенацию: "select * from mailer.log where id ="+id

Comment: Подставит. Но лучше используйте `PreparedStatement`.